# Haskell hoogle installed through cabal, but hoogle command not found

Tags: haskell, cabal, hoogle

The hoogle (hoogle-4.2.36) installation process looks successful, except that when typing "hoogle" at the command line, it complains "hoogle: command not found".

Tried this on two machines (both running MAC OS X Yosemite), they failed exactly the same way. Any suggestions to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `~/.cabal/bin` on your path?

Comment: If you've installed the Haskell Platform on OSX, look in `$HOME/Library/Haskell/bin` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to your information, I found my "hoogle" executable in ".cabal/bin". Alas, why doesn't cabal add it to PATH?